# How does git calculate the diff stat?

Tags: git

I'm curious when I do a `git diff --stat` I get a neat heuristic graph like so:

```
 editions/tw5.com/tiddlers/about/History of TiddlyWiki.tid         |  4 +++-
 licenses/cla-individual.md                                        |  2 ++
 plugins/tiddlywiki/text-slicer/modules/commands/slice.js          | 12 ++++++++----
 plugins/tiddlywiki/text-slicer/modules/slicer.js                  | 30 +++++++++++++-----------------
 plugins/tiddlywiki/text-slicer/modules/startup/slicer-message.js  |  4 +++-
 plugins/tiddlywiki/text-slicer/styles.tid                         | 57 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++---
 plugins/tiddlywiki/text-slicer/templates/interactive/document.tid | 18 +++++++++---------
 plugins/tiddlywiki/text-slicer/templates/interactive/heading.tid  | 10 +++++-----
 plugins/tiddlywiki/text-slicer/ui/edit-template-segment.tid       | 35 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 plugins/tiddlywiki/text-slicer/ui/filters/Orphans.tid             |  5 +++++
 plugins/tiddlywiki/text-slicer/ui/preview-column.tid              |  6 ++++++
 plugins/tiddlywiki/text-slicer/ui/tiddler/toolbar/title.tid       |  2 +-
 plugins/tiddlywiki/text-slicer/ui/view-template-segment.tid       | 30 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++--
 13 files changed, 172 insertions(+), 43 deletions(-)
```

The final *change*, *insertions*, and *deletions* I can gather how they are constructed.

However, how are the `2 +-` graphs calculated if I wanted to recreate this output on my own?

Comment: It looks like 'insertions + deletions' for that file. (The column adds up to 172 + 43).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number is the sum of inserted and deleted lines, for each file. For example `4 +++-` means 3 lines were inserted and 1 was deleted in the file.

If there is enough space for output, the number of `+` and `-` correspond to the exact number of inserted and deleted lines. If there is not enough space, the number of `+` and `-` are proportional to the number of inserted and deleted lines.